# Generating models from Database with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a Django project running on production with PostgreSQL.

I want to spin a separate FastAPI microservice to do a specific task, and I want it to communicate directly with the database I have hooked up with Django.

I do not want to rewrite all the models in FastAPI using pydantic, and at the same time I don't want to make a mistake.

In Django, there is `python manage.py inspectdb` to automatically generate models using an existing database. Is there an equivalent in FastAPI, SQLAlchemy or Pydantic?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [sqlacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen). It's a tool that reads the structure of an existing database and generates the appropriate SQLAlchemy model code.

It currently offeres a variety of built-in different generators:

- tables (only generates Table objects, for those who don't want to use the ORM)
- declarative (the default; generates classes inheriting from declarative_base())
- dataclasses (generates dataclass-based models; v1.4+ only)
- sqlmodels (generates model classes for [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/))

Declarative is the default, and generates standard SQLAlchemy models which you can use in your FastAPI application. You can also explore the `sqlmodels` generator as SQLModel is designed to simplify interacting with SQL databases in FastAPI applications (and it was created by the same author as FastAPI).